# what argument i can give when execute unix executable

Tags: io-redirection

It just occur to me that following command can print output in text file.

```
./a.out < infile.txt > actualoutput.txt
```

But i still wondering what < infile.txt > is for?

And what other arguments  i can give when executing this object file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the file that will be used as the standard input ( aka **stdin** ).
Your command is the same as

```
cat infile.txt | a.out > output.txt
```

Comment: What is meant by standard input (aka stdin)?

Comment: do you mean it started to get input from infile.txt instead of keyboard?

Comment: ... for some meaning of "same as" which I don't share. :)

Answer (score 1):

The < infile.txt means take standard input from infile.txt.

Similarly > actualoutput.txt means to send standard output to actualoutput.txt.

For more information on redirection take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).